# redirecting with url_for to a path with query params in flask

Tags: python, flask

So let's say I have a template with a couple of links, the links will be like this:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' href='/?chart=new_chart&chart=other_chart'>View Summary</a>
```

However, most of the times when I have done links or included resources, I have used the following syntax:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='some_silly_js') }}"></script>
```

is it possible to do a url_for with query parameters? Something like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('stats', query_params={chart: [new_chart, other_chart]}) }}>View More</a>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Any *extra* keyword parameters passed to `url_for()` which are not supported by the route are automatically added as query parameters.

For repeated values, pass in a list:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('stats', chart=[new_chart, other_chart]) }}>View More</a>
```

Flask will then:

1. find the `stats` endpoint
2. fill in any required route parameters
3. transform any remaining keyword parameters to a query string

Demo, with `'stats'` being the endpoint name for `/`:

```
>>> url_for('stats', chart=['foo', 'bar'])
'/?chart=foo&chart=bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation:

```
Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments.
```

I have tried this and it works as per the documentation

```
redirect(url_for('face_id_detail', faceid=faceid, name=faceidtag))
```

Note: faceid is the parameter in the method && name is not in the method parameters so it is appending to querystring.

The method signature for `face_id_detail` is:

```
@app.route('/faceids/<faceid>')
def face_id_detail(faceid):
    # the method code
```